# How can I create a custom crontab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, cron

I want a crontab to run every 15 minutes starting from 9:45 to 16:00.

I currently have this:

```
crontab(minute='*/15', hour='9:45-16', day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri')
```

but `9:45` is not valid

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this purpose you cannot do this in one command it is better to do it in two cron commands

```
crontab(minute='*/15', hour='10-16', day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri')
crontab(minute='45', hour='9', day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri')
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html). Run [crontab(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) or edit `/etc/crontab` according to your needs (perhaps using [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)  thru `sudo`). Of course you might use some Python library editing these textual files.

I see no reason to use Python for your purposes. Of course, you could run your Python script from `cron`, or any other executable. See [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Beware that your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) could be different for a script started from `cron` and in your interactive shell.